# Python Card Game

Tags: python

There's a fun card game I like to play when I'm with a group of nerds.

The rules are simple: One person places down four cards. In this version of the game, royals count as 10. The point of the game is to make 24 by using any binary operator. As an example:

10, 2, 3, 6

(10-6)*(2*3)

4*6

24

So... why not use computers to solve this for me with brute force?

```
from math import floor,ceil

for i in range(1000): # not 10,000 yet. It would run too long.
    one, two, three, four = i//(1000)+1,(i%1000)//100+1,(i%100)//10+1,i%10+1
    operand = [int.__add__,
               int.__sub__,
               int.__mul__,
               int.__truediv__,
               int.__pow__,
               int.__mod__,
               int.__or__, # even though I'd have to be a pedant to use these, I'm still curious
               int.__and__,
               int.__xor__,
               int.__lshift__,
               int.__rshift__]
    op_str = {int.__add__:"+",
                int.__sub__:"-",
                int.__mul__:"*",
                int.__truediv__:"/",
                int.__pow__:"**",
                int.__mod__:"%",
                int.__or__:"|",
                int.__and__:"&",
                int.__xor__:"^",
                int.__lshift__:"<<",
                int.__rshift__:">>"}
    for j in range(pow(len(operand),3)):
        try:
            a = operand[j%len(operand)]
            b = operand[(j%(len(operand)**2))//len(operand)]
            c = operand[(j%(len(operand)**3))//(len(operand)**2)]
            # serial
            answer = a(one,b(two,c(three,four)))
            if ceil(answer) == floor(answer) and answer == 24: 
                print(one, op_str[a], "(", two, op_str[b], "(", three, op_str[c], four, "))")
                print(one, op_str[a], "(", two, op_str[b], "(", c(three, four), "))")
                print(one, op_str[a], "(", b(two,c(three,four)), ")")
                print(a(one,b(two,c(three,four))))
                continue
            # tree
            answer = c(a(one, two), b(three, four))
            if ceil(answer) == floor(answer) and answer == 24: 
                print("((", one, op_str[a], two, ")", op_str[b], "(", three, op_str[c], four, "))")
                print("(", a(one, two), op_str[b], c(three, four), ")")
                print(c(a(one, two), b(three, four)))
                continue
        except Exception:
            pass # I just want to bypass any stupid problems with modulus, divide and the shifts
```

Except, I'm getting silly answers:

```
...
(( 1 % 1 ) * ( 6 | 4 ))
( 0 * 6 )
24
(( 1 - 1 ) * ( 6 + 4 ))
( 0 * 10 )
24
...
```

Anybody seeing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your code very hard to follow, so I thought I'd try a more structured  approach:

```
import operator as ops
from itertools import permutations, combinations_with_replacement

op = { symbol : getattr(ops, name) for name, symbol in dict(add     = '+',
                                                            sub     = '-',
                                                            mul     = '*',
                                                            truediv = '/').items() }
                  # etc. I'll let you fill in the rest

class Expression(object):

    def __init__(self, opsymbol, left, right):
        self.op       = op[opsymbol]
        self.opsymbol = opsymbol
        self.left     = left
        self.right    = right

    def __repr__(self):
        return "({left} {opsymbol} {right})".format(**vars(self))

    def eval(self):
        left  = evalexp(self.left)
        right = evalexp(self.right)
        return self.op(left, right)

    def show(self):
        return '{} = {}'.format(self, self.eval())

    def __hash__(self):        return hash(repr(self))
    def __eq__  (self, other): return repr(self) == repr(other)

def evalexp(e):
    return e.eval() if type(e) is Expression else e

def search(*args, target=24):
    assert len(args) == 4
    found = set()
    operators = tuple(combinations_with_replacement(op, 3))
    for a,b,c,d in permutations(args):
        for op1, op2, op3 in operators:
            for o1, o2, o3 in permutations((op1, op2, op3)):

                t1 = Expression(o1, a, Expression(o2, b, Expression(o3, c, d)))
                t2 = Expression(o1, a, Expression(o2, Expression(o3, b, c), d))
                t3 = Expression(o1, Expression(o2, a, b), Expression(o3, c, d))
                t4 = Expression(o1, Expression(o2, a, Expression(o3, b, c)), d)
                t5 = Expression(o1, Expression(o2, Expression(o3, a, b), c), d)

                for e in (t1, t2, t3, t4, t5):
                    try:
                        if e.eval() == target:
                            found.add(e)
                    except (ZeroDivisionError):
                        pass
    return found

found = search(2,3,6,10, target=24)
for e in found:
    print(e.show())
```

which gives 56 lines of output, including

```
((10 - 6) * (2 * 3)) = 24
((10 - (2 * 3)) * 6) = 24
(((6 + 10) * 3) / 2) = 24.0
((2 + 10) * (6 / 3)) = 24.0
(((10 + 6) * 3) / 2) = 24.0
((3 / 2) * (6 + 10)) = 24.0
(3 * ((6 + 10) / 2)) = 24.0
((2 * (10 - 6)) * 3) = 24
(6 * ((10 + 2) / 3)) = 24.0
((2 - 10) * (3 - 6)) = 24
(2 * (3 * (10 - 6))) = 24
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just a few typos in your printouts. You define your "tree" calculation as:

```
answer = c(a(one, two), b(three, four))
```

with `c` as the outermost function. But then you print it with `b` as the outermost function. These lines:

```
print("((", one, op_str[a], two, ")", op_str[b], "(", three, op_str[c], four, "))")
print("(", a(one, two), op_str[b], c(three, four), ")")
```

should read:

```
print("((", one, op_str[a], two, ")", op_str[c], "(", three, op_str[b], four, "))")
print("(", a(one, two), op_str[c], b(three, four), ")")
```

Your answer would then read:

```
...
(( 1 % 1 ) | ( 6 * 4 ))
( 0 | 24 )
24
(( 1 - 1 ) + ( 6 * 4 ))
( 0 + 24 )
24
...
```